# Keras Progress Bar not working on windows 10

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, keras-2

I am having issues on Windows 10, Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook properly displaying the Keras progress bar.  As you can see from the image attached, the output is all being concatenated as a long string with verbose=1 instead of properly backspacing and resetting. I'm guessing that the issue is that somehow the notebook is not properly interpreting the \b character, but I can't seem to find a way around this. Has anybody encountered a similar issue? I can train with verbose=2, but I would really like to be able to see the estimated time remaining.  Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442276/keras-verbose-training-progress-bar-writing-a-new-line-on-each-batch-issue) on here suggest issues where the progress bar is simply putting each batch on a new line, and the resulting diagnosis was that "It seems as if the info makes the bar too long for the terminal and so it breaks to a new line." so the solution was to make the terminal wider. However, this is (to my knowledge) not possible in a jupyter notebook. Can anybody suggest any alternatives to dealing with this?

[image]

Comment: You could try [keras-tqdm](https://github.com/bstriner/keras-tqdm). I use it with `verbose=1` or `verbose=2` for pretty much the same reason that you mention.

Comment: @petezurich, wow Ill have to get that right away!

Comment: @djk47463 ;0) Glad you might like it...

Answer (score 1):

reese0106,

I just had a similar issue, with long string output from Keras with *verbose=1* option.

It turned out that such behavior was caused by some conflict with imported tqdm library. To identify this I removed recent additional imports until keras started behave normally. Then I re-wrote my code to avid using tqdm. 
See my case described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443200/keras-floods-jupyter-cell-output-during-fit-verbose-1).