# Keras floods Jupyter cell output during fit (verbose=1)

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tqdm

When running keras model inside Jupyter notebook with "verbose=1" option, I started getting not single line progress status updates as before, but a flood of status lines updated at batch. See attached picture.  Restarting jupyter or the browser is not helping. 
Jupyter notebook server is: 5.6.0, keras is 2.2.2, Python is Python 3.6.5
**Please help.**

**cell content:**

*history = model.fit(x=train_df_scaled, y=train_labels, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, **verbose=1,** validation_data=(validation_df_scaled, validation_labels), shuffle=True)*

**output flood example:** (it is thousands of lines like this)

*loss: 217.5794 - mean_absolute_error: 11.166 - ETA: 32:42 - loss: 216.9500 - mean_absolute_error: 11.165 - ETA: 32:21 - loss: 216.6378 - mean_absolute_error: 11.164 - ETA: 32:00 - loss: 216.0345 - mean_absolute_error: 11.164 - ETA: 31:41 - loss: 215.6621 - mean_absolute_error: 11.166 - ETA: 31:21 - loss: 215.4639 - mean_absolute_error: 11.171 - ETA: 31:02 - loss: 215.1654 - mean_absolute_error: 11.173 - ETA: 30:44 - loss: 214.6583 - mean_absolute_error: 11.169 - ETA: 30:27 - loss: 213.8844 - mean_absolute_error: 11.164 - ETA: 30:10 - loss: 213.3308 - mean_absolute_error: 11.163 - ETA: 29:54 - loss: 213.1179 - mean_absolute_error: 11.167 - ETA: 29:37 - loss: 212.8138 - mean_absolute_error: 11.169 - ETA: 29:25 - loss: 212.7157 - mean_absolute_error: 11.174 - ETA: 29:11 - loss: 212.5421 - mean_absolute_error: 11.177 - ETA: 28:56 - loss: 212.1867 - mean_absolute_error: 11.178 - ETA: 28:42 - loss: 211.8032 - mean_absolute_error: 11.180 - ETA: 28:28 - loss: 211.4079 - mean_absolute_error: 11.179 - ETA: 28:15 - loss: 211.2733 - mean_absolute_error: 11.182 - ETA: 28:02 - loss: 210.8588 - mean_absolute_error: 11.179 - ETA: 27:50 - loss: 210.4498 - mean_absolute_error: 11.178 - ETA: 27:37 - loss: 209.9327 - mean_absolute_error: 11.176 - ETA: 27:*

Comment: Eh ... you forgot to ask a question. Also if you don't want verbose output, maybe don't set verbose to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few tests I found that the error is related to tqdm import. Tqdm was used in a piece of code which was later rewritten withoout it. Even though I was not using tqdm in this notebook, just having it imported affected the keras output.
To fix it I just commented out this line:
**from tqdm import tqdm**
and everything went fine, with nice keras progress bars. Not sure how exactly it conflicted with keras though...

Comment: Mark yourself as the answer!

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I cannot help but import tqdm (it's included with tensorflow/datasets). Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

verbose=2 should be used for interactive outputs.

Comment: I tried _verbose = 2_ but it only shows the epoch number, no loss data or ETA.
What puzzles me is that just until 2 days ago I was getting normal input. There were no major changes in my software - don't know what broke.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your installation (most likely of Jupyter or some browser issue). Generally the output should be identical, but overwriting the line instead of writing it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I would recommend:

- Try restarting Jupyter Notebook server.
- Try different browser other
  than what you're using; perhaps your browser got some update and it's
  breaking stuff! (usually, chrome is bad with notebooks!)